# How to attach a combobox in a status line in eclipse rcp application

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-rcp

I want to insert a combobox with 3 messages in my status bar in eclipse rcp application.Please tell me how to do it.

Comment: Wasssupp guys.......no answer,,,,,is it so tough?

Comment: Wasssupp sam… no validated answer? :-)

Comment: possible duplicate of [Contributing to the Status Bar/Trim in Eclipse RCP](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2810510/contributing-to-the-status-bar-trim-in-eclipse-rcp)

Answer (score 1):

You can insert any kind of control into the status bar by extending `org.eclipse.jface.action.ControlContribution`.

http://help.eclipse.org/helios/topic/org.eclipse.platform.doc.isv/reference/api/org/eclipse/jface/action/ControlContribution.html

http://www.eclipse.org/forums/index.php?t=msg&goto=517599&